# Xcode でビルド時に The simulator can not be launched because it's already in use というエラーが出る

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode5.1を使っています。プロジェクトをビルドした時、件名のようなエラーが出てしまいます。どの様にすれば直るでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### "the simulator can not be launched because it's already in use"

1. First of all quit your simulator. まず第一に、あなたのシミュレータを終了
2. And then force quit your xcode.  そして、あなたのXcodeを強制終了
3. And then run your project.  そして、あなたのプロジェクトを実行する

参考: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22953540

Comment: 参考リンクを追加しました。特にそのまま回答を写す場合は、出典も忘れないようにしてください。